# Partial match between 2 column and output yes, no in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Trying to do a partial match between the two columns and generate Yes or No if they do have a partial match on the third column

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A2,"PartialText*"),TRUE,FALSE) I used this but not sure about how to compare with column B2 and create output of Yes,No if there is a partial match

Comment: So are you trying to compare between two adjacent cells, like `Current Vendor` Cell A2 `FGP SYSTEMS LTD` with `Previous Vendor` Cell B2 `PGT Ceewrite` and same goes for the other cells in both of the columns? is that so?

Comment: Or is it you want to compare each cell `Current Vendor` column with the whole of `Previous Vendor` Column, if so how many `YES` you should have in reference to the image you have shared.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya i used =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("*"&Q2&"*",$S$2:$S$25807,1,0)),"Yes","No")
to check if the current vendor name matches or partial matches with the previous vendor name, for some of them it works and some it doesn't.

Comment: Not sure how is that above formula is working for you, without any wildcard however you may try this one `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("*"&Q2&"*",$S$2:$S$25807,1,0)),"Not Found","Yes")` , i found two matches as per the image shared so the match was for `TRELLEBORG SEALING SOLUTIONS`  also note since some are LTD for Limited it cannot match them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the names given, you'd expect three "Yes" answers - for Trelleborg and Moog?

You could try this: get the first word from column B, and see if it's present in column A.

To get the first word, find the first space.

```
=FIND(" ", @B:B)
```

Get that many letters (minus 1 for the space) from B:

```
=LEFT(@B:B,FIND(" ", @B:B)-1)
```

Find that word in column A. Use `SEARCH` not `FIND` for a case-insensitive search:

```
=SEARCH(LEFT(@B:B,FIND(" ", @B:B)-1),@A:A)
```

This will give a number or an error. Let's make that be `FALSE` or `TRUE`:

```
=ISERROR(SEARCH(LEFT(@B:B,FIND(" ", @B:B)-1),@A:A))
```

Finally let's turn that into "No" (is true, an error, no match found) or "Yes" (if false, not an error, match found)

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(LEFT(@B:B,FIND(" ", @B:B)-1),@A:A)),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: Sir, very nice explanation !!! I like when someone gives an explanation with the solution, thank you very much!